# Do I need to worry about endianess on Android if I'm not using the NDK?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have several functions that hash a `String` into a `ByteArray` and now I want to read a `UShort` from the array. Do I need to worry about endianess in Android under these circumstances? And if not, which endian should I assume? To be clear I'm creating all of this in memory not reading from different machines.

I've seen sources that say [Android is Little Endian](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) but that's in relation to using the NDK. And also that the [JVM is Big Endian](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) but I'm not technically targeting a traditional JVM (although on my development machine I'm obviously running one).

So this has left me quite confused. Do I always need to check? Or can I assume one? What implications for this have when it comes to running on the many weird processors sorted by Android?

Comment: It does not matter what processors your app is running on. JVM is always BigEndian by the way. It is only useful when dealing with external data (elf,mp4,file,etc..) and one parameter in your method does not hurt anybody either.

Comment: Thanks, the JVM is but does that hold true for Android as well? I can't find a definite answer.

Comment: Of course, you can write a program in `Java` or `Kotlin` but `Kotlin` still depends on `JVM`. Kotlin's standard library totally depends on the `Java` class library. It focused on safety, clarity, and interoperability.